# Requests can't be forwarded to peer network because the peer project disabled DNS peering

Tags: domain-name-system, lets-encrypt, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to get `cert-manager` works with my `GKE`. I had followed the official documents and had tried `dns01` [with no luck](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1461).

Currently I believe I found the missing manual it called [customized DNS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud6x06KaD7U). In the 11:00 of the video has not shown any exclamation mark, but I do.

**Ultimate Goal:**

get the `let's encrypt` certificate with automatic renewal

**Question:**
How to get rid of `Requests can't be forwarded to peer network because the peer project disabled DNS peering`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue, but you can ignore the message, it has no implications.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128510674

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't explicitly say that the message is safe to ignore, only that others have encountered it too.  It would be good to give a longer explanation, or find a more explicit reference.

Comment: I confirm. With your answer. I achieve `cert-manager` on my GKE.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159352/got-certificaes-tls-crt-and-tls-key-but-browser-still-raise-connection-is-not-p